# SQLAlchemy: get concrete class type of a relationship

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm looking to get the class/type of a relationship in sqlalchemy.

```
class Parent(CustomBase):
    children = relationship("Child")

class Child(Base):
    pass
```

Is there a way to get the type of `Parent.children` (`== Child`) when you only have access to Parent?

(For context this is done from a CustomBase class, hence why I don't know what the relation type is beforehand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this information through `Parent`'s mapper by following these steps:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

parent_mapper = sa.inspect(Parent)
child_mapper = parent_mapper.relationships['children'].entity
child_entity = child_mapper.entity
print(child_entity)
```

Output:

```
<class '__main__.Child'>
```

This code is equivalent, but accesses `Parent`'s mapper directly:

```
child_entity = Parent.__mapper__.relationships['children'].entity.entity
```

Comment: Fantastic, `inspect` is the way to go!